# VBA why am i getting error or popup saying "16"

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In the code shown below, i am in the first section moving data from sheet "Ark2" to the sheet "Ark1". in the second section, i transpose from vertical to horizontal. Now i am rinning it in module, but i am getting an popup saying "16" and it is deleting data from my sheet "Ark2" and therefor also data on ark2.

it is not adding data from the first sheet to the second or horizonting the colums.

hope you can help!!

[image: The sheet i get data from]

[image]

```
   Sub MyProcedure()
a = Worksheets("ark1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox (a)

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim nøgletal As String, år As Integer
    Worksheets("Ark2").Select
    nøgletal = Range("B2")
    år = Range("C2")
    Worksheets("Ark1").Select
    Worksheets("Ark1").Range("A4").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("C1:C100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("C12:C100").Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("D1:D100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("D12:D100").Value
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("E1:E100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("M12:M100").Value
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("F1:F100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("N12:N100").Value
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("G1:G100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("O12:O100").Value
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("A1:A16").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("A12:A16").Value
    If Worksheets("Ark1").Range("A4").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Ark1").Range("A4").End(xlDown).Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = nøgletal
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = år
    Worksheets("Ark2").Select
    Worksheets("Ark2").Range("B2", "B16").Select
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub x()

Dim lngDataColumns As Long
Dim lngDataRows As Long

lngDataColumns = 3
lngDataRows = 4

For t = 1 To lngDataRows

Range("l2").Offset(((t - 1) * lngDataColumns) - 1, 0).Resize(lngDataColumns, 1).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(Range("e1:g1").Value)

Range("M2").Offset(((t - 1) * lngDataColumns) - 1, 0).Resize(lngDataColumns, 1).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(Range("e1:g1").Offset(t).Value)

Next t

End Sub
```

Comment: You are showing the row number in the message box. 16 is the last row in Column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why am i getting error or popup saying “16”

Should be evident why if you add a value in say ark1!A17 and rerun:

```
Sub MyProcedure()
a = Worksheets("ark1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox (a)
End Sub
```

If not, try adding also into ark1!A18 and rerunning.